# Angular 16. Html video doesn't work when src is set using component property

Tags: angular

I am very frustrated, I can only use static urls in my video. This breaks any change that the dynamics of Angular provides. If anyone could help me?

This doesn't work:

```
   <video autoplay="false" width="640" height="360" controls>
        <source src="{{video}}" type="video/mp4"> //here
        <source src="{{model.profileVerification.video}}" type="video/mp4">
        Seu navegador não suporta o elemento de vídeo.
    </video>
```

This works:

```
     <video autoplay="false" width="640" height="360" controls>
        <source src="https://staticurlworksblahblah.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="{{model.profileVerification.video}}" type="video/mp4">
        Seu navegador não suporta o elemento de vídeo.
    </video>
```

Comment: `autoplay="false"`... *To disable video autoplay, autoplay="false" will not work; the video will autoplay if the attribute is there in the <video> tag at all. To remove autoplay, the attribute needs to be removed altogether.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attributes

Comment: But I can't reproduce the issue [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so77188141-video-player?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that Angular cannot ensure that `@Input` will contain a safe URL and therefore it refuses to use it.

You'll need to manually sanitize the URL using a custom pipe or bypassing the security trust.

Just bypassing it is not recommended as an attacker could load a malicious URL into your video, therefore the restriction in the first place.

```js
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
    name: "bypassSecurity"
})
export class BypassSecurityPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(v: string): SafeHtml {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
    }
}
```

and on your template:

```html
<video autoplay="false" width="640" height="360" controls>
 <source [src]="videoUrl | bypassSecurity"/>
 Seu navegador não suporta o elemento de vídeo.
</video>
```